# Oracle 11g - Recursive Table - How to show information from a simple recursive table

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

Beginner here...

If I have a table that has some recursion and need help showing the following.

Table of college students, some of whom are Teachers as well as students.  So, some of the students can teach other students, as they are teachers.

```
|SID|  FName  |  LName  |  Phone  |  Teacher  |

----------------------------------------------------------

|1 |  John   |  Smtih  |  123    |  Null     |

|2 |  Susan  |  Johnson|  321    |  1        |

|3 |  Jane   |  Doe    |  456    |  1        | 

|4 |  Mike   |  Jones  |  654    |  Null     |

|5 |  Doug   |  Houston|  789    |  4        |
```

The teacher field relates to the `Student_ID` field (thus the recursive nature of this table).

I need to come up with the SQL commands show the following table (FName, LName and the name of the teacher):

```
|  FName  |  LName  |  Teacher    |

-----------------------------------

|  John   |  Smtih  |  Null       | 

|  Susan  |  Johnson|  John Smith | 

|  Jane   |  Doe    |  John Smith | 

|  Mike   |  Jones  |  Null       | 

|  Doug   |  Houston|  Mike Jones |
```

If I run the following:

```
SELECT FName,LName,Teacher
FROM TableA;
```

I get most of what I need, but Teacher is represented by the `Student_ID`.  How Do I get the Name of the Student to appear where `Student_ID` is appearing?

Answer (score 0):

You can self-join to the same table, do it as an outer join to allow for the null teacher values, and concatenate the first name/last name of the Teacher.  Something like this:

```
SELECT a.FName, a.LName, b.FName || ' ' || b.LName
  FROM TableA a
  LEFT JOIN TableA b ON (a.Teacher = b.SID)
```